# Will i have to develop separate Apple Watch app for each version of mobile app?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

Apple watch has been developed for mobile app version lets say it is 1.0. Now mobile app has been upgraded to version 2.0.

Do i need to develop separate apple watch for app version 2.0 or any other way to integrate(apple watch) with latest mobile app(version 2.0)?

Answer (score 0):

If you change version of your iOS app in *Info.plist*, you also have to change version of watchOS app to the same version as is of your iOS app.